# jQuery - $.ajax returns other dataFormat as $post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I use $.ajax to get data from the server the format looks different from a $.post request result. How can I change the $.post request in order to receive the same format as with the $.ajax request? Otherwise I cannot use my for-Loop to read out the data:

Working code with $ajax:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "/fetchdata.php",
                type: "POST",                   
                dataType: "json",
                data: "param=no",
                success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

                    $('#DOM').append('<li>'+ data[i].username +'</li>');
                    }
                },
                error: function(e){
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
```

Result of $.ajax in console:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

not working code with $.post:

```
            var jqxhr = $.post( "/fetchdata.php", function(data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

                                $('#DOM').append('<li>'+ data[i].username +'</li>');
                                }
                })
                  .done(function() {
                  })
                  .fail(function() {
                  })
                  .always(function() {
            });
```

Result of $.post in console:

```
 [{"id_usesrs":"1","username":"A"},{"id_usesrs":"2","username":"B"},{"id_usesrs":"3","username":"C"},  
 {"id_usesrs":"4","username":"D"}]
```

Comment: You need to use the `{ data: no }` in your `$.post` request just as you use it in your `$.ajax` request and include a data type. Other than that I do not see any difference in the calls.

Comment: `dataType: "json"` might be making the difference. When set it will parse the data for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that it returns JSON and not a string

```
$.post("/fetchdata.php", function(data) { ... }, 'json')
```

The last parameter of `$.post()` is the equivalent of `dataType` in `$.ajax()`

More info http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 1):

In $.post the return data type is not specified,

use this

```
            var jqxhr = $.post( "/fetchdata.php", function(data) {
                                                console.log(data);
                                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

                                            $('#DOM').append('<li>'+ data[i].username +'</li>');
                                            }
                            },'json')
                              .done(function() {
                              })
                              .fail(function() {
                              })
                              .always(function() {
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, that on your $.post, there is no reaturn datatype specified and the standard for datatype is "intelligent guess" (compare http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).
So the server returns a json-format string and the $.post method interpretates that as a string, not an object. This string that can be turned into a json-object with JSON.parse(string);
In your $.ajax call you definitely define the return type as json and so the $.ajax mehtod automatically uses JSON.parse on the string. You can use the optional datatype parameter for the $.post method (as shown in the jquery api spec):

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "/fetchdata.php", function(data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

                                $('#DOM').append('<li>'+ data[i].username +'</li>');
                                }
                }, "json")
                  .done(function() {
                  })
                  .fail(function() {
                  })
                  .always(function() {
            });
```